# Find most frequent item in array

Tags: bash

How do I find the most frequent number over a range of numbers in Bash?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

frequent=0

analog=(889 890 884 880 889 889 884 885 890 890)

for i in ${analog[@]}; do
    # what to do whit this $i ?
done
```

Since the result is 2 which is 3x 889 and 3x 890, i prefer the result should be 890 (highest) instead 889.

Comment: Do you mean highest valued number (max) or the highest frequency (mode)?

Comment: @learnerer not max, but most frequent number. And pick the highest if found double. In the example 889 and 890 is same showed 3x.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use an *Associative Array* and the post-increment operator to increment a count of each number in your `analog` indexed array, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

analog=(889 890 884 880 889 889 884 885 890 890)
declare -A frequent

for i in ${analog[@]}; do
    ((frequent[$i]++))
done

for i in "${!frequent[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i ==> ${frequent[$i]}"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/array/freqarray.sh
880 ==> 1
884 ==> 2
885 ==> 1
889 ==> 3
890 ==> 3
```

You can simply keep a `max` count as you iterate the associative array and output the `key` associated with the `max` frequent value (you have to determine how you handle the ties, e.g. `889, 890` are both `3`.)

Identifying the values with the maximum occurrences in analog, you could add  `maxkey` and `maxval` variables as you loop over the occurrences and then a final loop similar to:

```
declare -i maxkey=0 maxval=0
for i in "${!frequent[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i ==> ${frequent[$i]}"
    if (( ${frequent[$i]} > maxval )); then
        maxval=${frequent[$i]}
        maxkey=$i
    fi
done

printf "\nmaximum occurences in analog:\n\n"
for i in "${!frequent[@]}"; do
    if (( ${frequent[$i]} == maxval)); then
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i ==> ${frequent[$i]}"
    fi
done
```

Which would then produce the following output:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/array/freqarray.sh
880 ==> 1
884 ==> 2
885 ==> 1
889 ==> 3
890 ==> 3

maximum occurences in analog:

889 ==> 3
890 ==> 3
```

**Per Your Edit to Find Highest Value with Maximum Occurrence**

To find the highest value with the maximum occurrence, you can simply add an additional check in your second loop and set the `maxkey` value to the highest value in `frequent` that has the `maxval`. For example you can rearrange your final loop and add the output as follows:

```
printf "\nmaximum occurences in analog:\n\n"
for i in "${!frequent[@]}"; do
    if (( ${frequent[$i]} == maxval)); then
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i ==> ${frequent[$i]}"
        (( i > maxkey)) && maxkey=i
    fi
done

printf "\nhighest value with maximum occurrence:\n\n"
printf "%d\n" $maxkey
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ~/scr/array/freqarray.sh
880 ==> 1
884 ==> 2
885 ==> 1
889 ==> 3
890 ==> 3

maximum occurences in analog:

889 ==> 3
890 ==> 3

highest value with maximum occurrence:

890
```

Comment: Thank you this is so fast, and that is sad to have -1 in my question. BTW, how can we get the highes? Im still new in bash.

Comment: If you just care about finding the first number that satisfies the maximum occurrence, you could use `printf "\nmax is %d (%d occurrances)\n" $maxkey ${frequent[$maxkey]}`

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. There is no maximum occurrence. Just find the highest value. 890 instead of 889.

Comment: Ok, that makes it much, much easier. Just `declare -i max=0; for i in ${analog[@]}; do (( i > max )) && max=$i; done; echo "max: $max"`. Or, if you wanted to use a utility like `sort`, then `printf "%s\n" ${analog[@]} | sort -n | tail -n1`

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43440425/most-frequent-element-in-an-array-bash-3-2), though the solution by PSkocik finds the minimum, instead of the maximum in the case of a tie. A simple inequality flip from `if(what>$1)` to 
`if(what< $1)` fixes that.

Comment: Yeah before i cannot found in stackoverflow, but now im still reading same solution as your link. And still trying to figure how to find highest. Thank you anyway. Prefer rici's answer